# MySQL Error - understanding it

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, insert, cursor, truncate

has anyone seen this sort of error and what it means?

I have a stored procedure which is simply running a cursor through 502 records and as it passes through the loop, inserts into a table, in essence a copy and paste but its only entering 239 of these records and i get this error

```
1265 Data truncated for column 'v_tagMemberSF' at row 5 
 1265 Data truncated for column 'v_tagMemberSF' at row 6 
 1265 Data truncated for column 'v_tagMemberSF' at row 7
 1265 Data truncated for column 'v_tagMemberSF' at row 10 
 1265 Data truncated for column 'v_tagMemberSF' at row 11 
 1265 Data truncated for column 'v_tagMemberSF' at row 12 
 1265 Data truncated for column 'v_tagMemberSF' at row 13 
 1265 Data truncated for column 'v_tagMemberSF' at row 14
```

The stored procedure with the cursor is

```
OPEN cur1;

    -- Start the Loop --
    dataSetLoop: LOOP

    -- get the values of each column into our variables declared in stored procedure

            FETCH cur1 INTO v_dateTime, v_val, v_numIndex, v_tagName, v_tagIndex, v_tagMemberSF, v_tagMemberMinVal, v_tagMemberMaxVal;

            if v_tagMemberSF = NULL then
            SET v_tagMemberSF = 1;
            END IF;

            -- Check if v_val is null first --
            INSERT INTO new_tempdata.looper (incremented, TagNameInserted) VALUES (v_dateTime, v_tagName);
            COMMIT;
            IF done THEN
                LEAVE dataSetLoop;
            END IF;


        END LOOP dataSetLoop;

    CLOSE cur1;

INSERT INTO new_tempdata.looper (incremented, TagNameInserted) Values (123456789,'ID29SP');

END
```

Does anyone have any idea what this might be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error mean your new_tempdata.looper table cant store data you trying to insert. Check length of fields *incremented* and *TagNameInserted*, must be same with *v_dateTime* & *v_tagName*;